# Why when I append text to a file it does not print it on a new line?

Tags: python

My code writes the data variable on the sameline as other entries and I wanted to print it on a new line after the code is excuted

for ex:

1234:paris jame:2:7:4
3234:Sally Tab:2:7:4

However my code appends to the file in this format

1234:paris jame:2:7:4  3234:Sally Tab:2:7:4

I have tried "/n" or end "" none worked

```
infile = open("students.dat","a")
data_entry = []
def add_student():
    id = (input('enter your id:'))
    name = input('enter your name:')
    semester = input('which semester are you in:')
    year = input('which year are you in')
    number_of_courses = input('how many courses do you take:')
    data = id + ":"+name+":"+year+":"+semester+":"+number_of_courses
    infile.write(data)
    infile.close()
add_student()
```

Comment: `write()` doesn't automatically add a newline. If you want a newline, you have to write it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Add a line break `\n` at beginning of the string:

```
data = f"\n{id}:{name}:{year}:{semester}:{number_of_courses}"
```

Note: a line break uses a backslash `\` not a common slash `/`